# Can pressure loss along the hydrodynamic entrance region be calculated?

Tags: energy, fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow

When a fluid first enters a pipe, I understand there can be a developing region as the boundary layer encompasses the flow (due to the no-slip condition). I have also heard that pressure loss in this hydrodynamic entrance region is increased due to an increased shear stress.

Is there a way to calculate the pressure loss caused in this region?

Comment: Yes, it can be calculated for laminar flow by solving the Naiver Stokes equations numerically using CFD software.  An approximate answer can be obtained by using the flat plate laminar BL equations until the BL thickness reaches a thickness of R.